# LaTeX hyphenation and line breaking not working

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I am unable to produce a simple text with hyphenated words and justified lines with PDFLatex.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,a4paper,twoside]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %It does not change anything
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{hyphenat} %It does not change anything

\begin{document}

    \kant[1]
    
    discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous 
            
\end{document}
```

here is the output

[image]

here is the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.9)  9 SEP 2020 13:54
entering extended mode
**./MWE.tex
(MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2020/06/10 3.45 The Babel package

(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/06/10 3.45 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count175
\U@D=\dimen135
\l@babelnohyphens=\language1

(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count176

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
))
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/kantlipsum/kantlipsum.sty
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-06-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-23 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count177
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2020-05-15 L3 Experimental document command parser

(/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.t
ex
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count178
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count179
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count180
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count181
))
Package: kantlipsum 2019/07/23 v0.8 Generate text in Kantian style
\l__kgl_start_int=\count182
\l__kgl_end_int=\count183

Package kantlipsum Info: The package provides paragraphs 1 to 164. Values
(kantlipsum)             outside this range will be ignored.

) (/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty
Package: indentfirst 1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [openright].

(MWE.aux)
\openout1 = `MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.

Overfull \hbox (56.62592pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 15--16
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous disco
ntinuous discontinuous
 []


Overfull \hbox (39.0011pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 15--16
\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discontinuous discont
inuous discontinuous
 []

[1

{/home/manu/.miktex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (MWE.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1545 strings out of 482723
 29689 string characters out of 2948875
 797065 words of memory out of 3000000
 17357 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532636 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 36i,4n,41p,224b,108s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
</home/ma
nu/.miktex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 16650 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

and here is a screenshot of the MikTex console:

[image]

Comment: Do you mind showing the log file for this example? Additionally the kantlipsum and its `\kant` macro can be a better idea than lupsum as kantlipsum uses texts in English

Comment: Yes, of course. Please see edited question.

Comment: `\l@babelnohyphens=\language1` looks as if you have no patterns loaded at all. What does the language tab in miktex console under settings show?

Comment: It shows: language: english; synonims: usenglish, USenglish, american; loader: hyphen.tex; package: knuth-lib; installed: (blank)

Comment: hm, that isn't much, and knuth-lib sounds definitively odd in this list. This looks as if your language.dat/ini is corrupted. Show a screenshot so that I can be sure.

Comment: Ok, see edited question

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much for your comments, they helped me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to MikTeX console in Administrator mode and updated `babel-english` and `hyph-utf8` packages. Now it works perfectly.